# Error: Cannot estimate gas; transaction may fail or may require manual gas limit (reason="execution reverted: You are not the owner of this token"

Tags: alchemy

below is code

```
function executeSale(uint256 tokenId) public payable {
        uint price = idToListedToken[tokenId].price;
        address seller = idToListedToken[tokenId].seller;
        require(msg.value == price, "Please submit the asking price in order to complete the purchase");

        //update the details of the token
        idToListedToken[tokenId].currentlyListed = true;
        idToListedToken[tokenId].seller = payable(msg.sender);
        _itemsSold.increment();

        //Actually transfer the token to the new owner
        _transfer(address(this), msg.sender, tokenId);
        //approve the marketplace to sell NFTs on your behalf
        approve(address(this), tokenId);

        //Transfer the listing fee to the marketplace creator
        payable(owner).transfer(listPrice);
        //Transfer the proceeds from the sale to the seller of the NFT
        payable(seller).transfer(msg.value);
    }
```